# поиск позиции многострочного текста

Tags: c, unix, shell

имеется большой текстовый `файл1`. например:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

имеется другой текстовый `файл2` с несколькими строками. например:

```
b
c
d
```

как с помощью *posix*-утилит (или хотя бы *gnu*-утилит, а в крайнем случае — на максимально платформо-неспецифичном *си*) найти номер строки в первом файле, начиная с которой эти файлы совпадают? для приведённого примера — это будет `2` (начиная со второй строки в первом файле содержатся точно такие же строки, как и во втором).

---

на данный момент нашёл лишь способ узнать, входит ли второй файл в первый:

```
$ grep -qzP "$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' файл2)" файл1 && echo входит
```

но он не позволяет узнать номер строки, с которой началось совпадение.

пояснение по поводу программы для *sed*: она заменяет каждый перевод строки в `файле2` на два символа `\n` (обратный слэш и `n`), чтобы получилось регулярное выражение для *grep*-а. позаимстовавана отсюда: [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251999/4827341).

Comment: а может написать код на перле?

Comment: @KoVadim, perl — это уже «тяжёлая артиллерия». вообще изложена лишь подзадача. глобальная задача — слить два частично пересекающихся файла: некоторое неизвестное количество строк в конце одного файла повторяется в начале другого, и требуется получить в одном файле: уникальные строки из первого, затем общие строки, затем уникальные строки из второго.

Comment: перл - это легкий инструмент. Но если хочется на стандарных утилитах...

Comment: А что в Вашем понимании "легковестно"? Проще написать или меньше ресурсов? Проще писать на том, что знаешь, а ресурсы - это си/асм

Comment: @KoVadim, предполагаемое место использования — «микрокомпьютер» (типа *raspberry pi* и слабее) или вообще что-нибудь на *openwrt*. так что ресурсы (в том числе и блобы с интерпретатором) — критичны. // а «си/асм», помимо бо́льших затрат времени на разработку/отладку, ввиду неопределённости целевой архитектуры (intel/arm/mips) — в некотором роде «оверхед».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### C помощью patch

```
if line=$(diff -U0 файл2 /dev/null | patch -f --dry-run файл1 - | sed -rn 's/^Hunk #1 succeeded at ([0-9]+) .*/\1/p; /FAILED/ q1')
then echo строка ${line:-1}
else echo фрагмент не найден
fi
```

Создаём патч удаляющий из файла-образца все строки и пытаемся его применить ко второму файлу в режиме проверки (dry-run). Если это возможно, `patch`  сообщает найденное смещение, если оно не нулевое. Если нет - сообщает об ошибке.

### С помощью diff.

Это был мой первый вариант, оставил его на всякий случай. Вроде работает, но как поведёт себя с очень большими файлами, не знаю:

```
diff -U0 файл2 файл1 | sed -rn '1!{/^-/q1}; 3{s/@@ -0,0 \+(1,([0-9]+)|(1)).*/\2\3/p}; /^@@ -[1-9]/ {G; h; /@@\n@@/ q1 }'
```

Только строки нумеруются с 0.

Возможно будет неоправданно долго работать с большим файлом, так как `diff` будет выводить весь `файл1` несовпадающий с `файл2`.

Если совпадений нет и при частичном совпадении возвращает статус 1, текст при этом стоит игнорировать.
Если файлы совпадают с самого начала, ничего не выводится, статус=0.

#### Пояснения по программе.

`diff -U0` выдаёт патч в унифицированном формате без контекстных строк.

Первая группа отлавливает строки начинающиеся с минуса, кроме первой строки. Если такие строки присутствуют, значит diff не нашёл какой-то строки из `файл2`, программа завершается с кодом ошибки 1.

Вторая группа отлавливает начало фрагмента который diff считает, как добавленное перед строками из `файл2`. Отсюда берётся число строк этого фрагмента. Заголовок этого фрагмента должен выглядеть как `@@ -0,0 +1,n @@`, где n - количество его строк. n равное 1 опускается.

Если в `файл1` есть все строки из `файл2`, но между ними есть ещё другие, в этом случае `diff` выдаст больше двух срок начинающихся с `@@` и ни одного минуса, последняя группа команд отслеживает это.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, напутал с копипастингом из терминала.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ещё ошибка была

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, любой, сейчас изменил, вроде должно засекать частичные совпадения

Comment: разбираюсь с программой для *sed-а*. поясните, пожалуйста, зачем там добавка `|(1)` в конструкции `([0-9]+)|(1)`? ведь с символом `1` совпадёт и первая часть — `([0-9]+)`, а значит альтернатива `(1)` — вроде бы излишня.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, когда только одна строка перед совпадением diff выдаёт @@ -0,0 +1 @@ в противном случае он выдаёт @@ -0,0 +1,n @@

Comment: немножко сократил и оптимизировал программу: `sed -rn '1!{/^-/q1}; 3{s/@@ -0,0 \+(1,([0-9]+)|(1)).*/\2\3/p}'`. теперь она не выдаёт никакого «мусора» при несовпадении файлов. вроде бы тесты проходит удачно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но так всегда нужно статус проверять. И ещё третья `s` отлавливает случай когда файлы совпадают с самого начала. Но если файлы полностью совпадают, то и у меня ничего не выводится.

Comment: *но между ними вставлены другие строки, это определится как совпадение* — это плохо. а что вы подразумевали под «это можно определить с помощью hold space»? то, что требуется доработка? // кстати, написал свой вариант, на *awk*. вроде всё корректно делает.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, доработал

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, придумал новый способ, думаю более правильный

Comment: с *patch*-ем — реально круто. спасибо! // вместо `echo -n` можно использовать `:`. или вообще заменить этот конвейер `/dev/null`-ом в качестве второго аргумента *diff*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я сначала отверг `/dev/null` потому, что `patch` в таком случае всегда возвращает ненулевой статус, но так как дальше ещё добавил `sed`, то его статус является статусом всей команды, поэтому `/dev/null` тоже можно.

Answer (score 2):

придумал вариант на *awk* (`скрипт.awk`):

```
BEGIN {
  n=1 # инициализируем номер строки
  r=1 # умолчальный код возврата - 1
} 

{
  # если удалось прочитать следующую строку из файла2
  if ((getline l < f2) > 0) {
    if (l!=$0) { # и она не равна очередной строке из файла1
      close(f2)  # то закрываем файл2 (очередной getline откроет его заново)
      n=NR+1     # кандидатом на совпадение считаем следующую строку файла1
    }
  } else {   # если файл2 закончился
    r=0      # код возврата - 0 (удача)
    print n  # номер строки, где началось совпадение
    nextfile # завершаем чтение текущего файла
             # а так он единственный - файл1 - то это означает переход
             # к секции END
  } 
} 

END {
  exit r # завершаем программу с указанным кодом возврата
}
```

вызывать так:

```
$ awk -v f2=файл2 -f скрипт.awk файл1
```

имя второго файла передаётся через переменную `f2`.

возвращает либо номер строки из `файла1`, начиная с которой `файл2` целиком содержится в `файл1`, либо ничего и код возврата — `1` («нет совпадения»).

можно вызывать и как однострочник. в этом случае имя второго файла проще внедрить прямо в код скрипта:

---

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{f2="файл2";n=1;r=1}{if((getline l<f2)>0){if(l!=$0){close(f2);n=NR+1}}else{r=0;print n;nextfile}}END{exit r}' файл1
```

Comment: если в `файл1` строку `b` повторить, не находит.

Comment: @sercxjo, спасибо за выявленный баг! нда, засада. чтоб такую ситуацию обработать, придётся сильно усложнять алгоритм.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы напечатать, где строки, общие для обоих файлов, начинаются в `файл1`:

```sh
$ diff \
    --old-group-format='' \
    --changed-group-format='' \
    --new-group-format='' \           
    --unchanged-group-format='%df'$'\n' файл1 файл2
2
```

[Line Group Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Group-Formats.html).

---

> глобальная задача — слить два частично пересекающихся файла: некоторое неизвестное количество строк в конце одного файла повторяется в начале другого, и требуется получить в одном файле: уникальные строки из первого, затем общие строки, затем уникальные строки из второго.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
function cleanup {
  rm -rf sorted{1,2}
}
trap cleanup EXIT

# sort, remove duplicates
sort -u файл1 > sorted1
sort -u файл2 > sorted2

# print unique lines from файл1
comm -23 sorted{1,2}
# print common lines 
comm -12 sorted{1,2}
# print unique lines from файл2
comm -13 sorted{1,2}
```

> в данном случае сортировка исключается: 1. важен порядок строк; 2. многие строки могут неоднократно повторяться. примерная аналогия: частично перекрывающиеся лог-файлы без меток времени

Чтобы объединить файлы, содержащие общие строчки:

```sh
$ diff \
--old-group-format='%<' \
--new-group-format='%>' \
old new
```

Comment: про «глобальную задачу» — спасибо, но в данном случае сортировка исключается: 1. важен порядок строк; 2. многие строки могут неоднократно повторяться. примерная аналогия: частично перекрывающиеся лог-файлы без меток времени.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: не вижу за что спасибо, если не подходит в вашем случае. Слово "уникальные" я неправильно интерпретировал (оно означает "строки не встречающиеся в другом файле" в данном случае, а не "неповторяющиеся"). Обновил ответ.

Comment: первое из выражений на модифицированном `файле1` (продублировал 3-ю строку, содержащую `c`) возвращает `25`. это значение вполне логично (с точки зрения *diff*), но, увы, является неправильным (в качестве ответа на вопрос). // у последнего (третьего) предложения такая же ситуация.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin `c` не может быть продублировано (тогда файл2 в файл1 не содержится)

Comment: а, понял: не проверяется факт наличия **полного** совпадения. ну, это не страшно — прямо в вопросе у меня приведён способ проверки. // кстати, если использовать не `'%df'`, а (для *bash*-а) `'%df'$'\n'`, то ответ будет многострочный и таким образом можно детектировать отсутствие **полного** совпадения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: верно, полное совпадение не проверяется. Первая `diff` команда печатает где общие для двух файлов группы строк начинаются (группа может состоять как из одной строчки общей для двух файлов так и из всего второго (меньшего) файла целиком). `$'\n'` не гарантирует что `файл2` не содержится в `файл1` целиком. `$'\n'` просто демонстрирует, что *несколько* групп с общими строчками могут присутствовать.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на Си для *nix с использованием [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), для максимальной экономии памяти.

```
// avp 2016 find one file (av[2]) into other file (av[1])
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct fmap {
  char *data; // don't maps empty (filesize == 0) files
  size_t len; // filesize from fstat
  int errn;   // errno after mapfile() (0 for empty file !!!)
};


struct fmap
mapfile (const char *fn)
{
  struct fmap fm = {0, 0, EINVAL}; // it's for C++ (it can't {.errn=EINVAL})

  if (fn) {
    int old = errno;
    errno = 0;
    int fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY);
    struct stat st;

    if (fd > -1)
      if ((fstat(fd, &st), fm.len = st.st_size) &&
          (fm.data = (char *)mmap(NULL, st.st_size,
                                  PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0))) {
        madvise(fm.data, fm.len, MADV_SEQUENTIAL);
        close(fd);
      }
    fm.errn = errno;
    errno = old;
  }

  return fm;
}

static inline size_t skipnl (struct fmap *p, size_t from) {
  while (from < p->len && p->data[from++] != '\n');

  return from;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac != 3)
    err(EX_USAGE,
        "search file2 in file1 (by lines) Usage: %s file1 file2", av[0]);
  struct fmap f1 = mapfile(av[1]),
    f2 = mapfile(av[2]);

  if (!f1.data) 
    (errno = f1.errn) ? err(EX_DATAERR, "file %s", av[1]) :
                        errx(EX_DATAERR, "empty file %s", av[1]);
  if (!f2.data)
    (errno = f2.errn) ? err(EX_DATAERR, "file %s", av[2]) :
                        errx(EX_DATAERR, "empty file %s", av[2]);

  size_t i = 0,
    lineno = 0, // current line number in f1
    n2l = 0;    // number of '\n' in f2 (for adjust lineno when found f2 in f1)
  for (i = 0; i < f2.len; i++)
    if (f2.data[i] == '\n')
      n2l++;
  // continue search after successful matching from the beginning of new line
  int need_skipnl = f2.data[f2.len - 1] != '\n';

  i = 0;
  while (i < f1.len) {
    if (memcmp(f1.data + i, f2.data, f2.len) == 0) {
      printf("%ld\n", (long)lineno + 1);
      lineno += n2l;
      i += f2.len;
      if (need_skipnl)
        i = skipnl(&f1, i), lineno++;
    } else
      i = skipnl(&f1, i), lineno++;
  }

  return munmap(f1.data, f1.len) + munmap(f2.data, f2.len) ? EX_OSERR : 0;
}
```

Возможно стоит как-то по другому спроектировать коды возврата. Например, если ничего не найдено, возвращать 1 (сейчас  (ubuntu /usr/include/sysexits.h) возвращает 0, 64, 65 и 71).

P.S.
граничные условия (размеры файлов кратны странице) не тестировал.